# function does not exists in postgreSQL .. Why ?

Tags: postgresql

Need your help please , can't understand why i got the following error , i am not a professional postgresql developer ..

As you can see the function created , so why the function not exist occurred ?

```
create or replace function loginAttempt (u_email character varying, u_password character varying, date_time timestamptz, OUT attempt smallint) returns smallint AS $$
   BEGIN
        INSERT INTO login_attempts (typed_password, date_time, attempt_nu, email) VALUES (u_password, date_time, attempt_nu, email);
        IF attempt = 3 THEN INSERT INTO warnings (u_email,u_password) VALUES (u_email,u_password);
        END IF;
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


  select loginattempt ('Jon.Jones88@gmail.com','+_@kjhfdb987', now(), 1);
```

> ERROR:  function loginattempt(unknown, unknown, timestamp with time zone, integer) does not exist
>   LINE 1: select loginattempt ('Jon.Jones88@gmail.com','+_@kjhfdb987',...
>                  ^
>   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   SQL state: 42883
>   Character: 8

[image]

Comment: What is your Postgres version (`select version();` will tell you)

Comment: PostgreSQL 10.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined the last parameter as an OUT parameter, that means you can't pass a value for it.

You need to use:

```
select loginattempt ('Jon.Jones88@gmail.com','+_@kjhfdb987', now());
```

As you are not writing to the parameter `attempts` I don't see a reason to define it as an out parameter to begin with. You can simply return the value if you need it:

```
create or replace function loginAttempt (u_email character varying, u_password character varying, u_date_time timestamptz, u_attempt smallint) 
  returns smallint 
AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO login_attempts (typed_password, date_time, attempt_nu, email) 
  VALUES (u_password, u_date_time, u_attempt, u_email);
  IF u_attempt = 3 THEN 
    INSERT INTO warnings (u_email,u_password) VALUES (u_email,u_password);
  END IF;
  return u_attempt;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As the value `1` is assumed to be an integer, you need to cast that value when calling the function:

```
select loginattempt ('Jon.Jones88@gmail.com','+_@kjhfdb987', now(), 1::smallint);
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/YNIQ55561

Comment: Why i got 2 unknown argument types in mine function loginattempt as you can see from the error message ?

Comment: @Maks.Burkov: you need to cast the `1` to a smallint. And you should also make sure your function parameters do not have the same name as your columns to avoid confusion